# iOS universal app: iPad is taking iPhone nib file (storyboard)

Tags: ios7, uistoryboard, ios-universal-app

I have Main_iPhone.storyboard and Main_iPad.storyboard files.
I have renamed the above files and renamed back and it stopped working. 
The problem had developed into this.
   - First iPad version was taking iPhone storyboard.
   - And then, it stopped working on both iPhone and iPad throwing the below error.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/BBB6A021-5C55-47B5-8BD9-C2510738BD59/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'Main_iPad''
```

Things I tried :

1. I have removed the references of the files and added them back to
   project
2. On the project build settings:  it has correct names mentioned.
3. My app .plist have the entries like below.

   Main nib file base name               Main_iPhone
   Main nib file base name (iPad)        Main_iPad

Still getting the same exception. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you added the nibs back to your project, the Main_iPad storyboard is not part of the Universal app's target.  Select the Main_iPad in the Project Navigator, then open the File Inspector (the leftmost icon in the right pane).  In the "Target Membership" section, make sure you have selected your app's target.